# com.vaadin.ui.DateField - time section not editable after toggling read-only

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin4spring

I have a form with a DateField and I want to be able to toggle between read-only mode and non-read-only/edit mode.

When the field is initially read-only and I switch to non-read-only then the time section of the calendar isn't editable/displayed correctly.

When the field is initially non-read-only toggling between non-read-only and read-only works es expected. The problem is  that the field initially needs to be read-only.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

I'm using vaadin 7.4.4 with vaadin-spring-boot-starter-1.0.0.beta2.

```
@SpringUI()
@Theme("valo")
public class TestUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        DateField dateField = new DateField();
        dateField.setResolution(Resolution.MINUTE);
        dateField.setValue(new Date());
        dateField.setReadOnly(true);

        Button button = new Button("toggle read-only");
        button.addClickListener(event ->   dateField.setReadOnly(!dateField.isReadOnly()));

        VerticalLayout pageLayout = new VerticalLayout(dateField, button);
        pageLayout.setSpacing(true);
        pageLayout.setMargin(true);

        setContent(pageLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds very much like a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known and reported bug, you can find it in Vaadin Trac Bug Reporting system - [Issue #17319](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/17319).

> **#17319 - Readonly date field with Resolution.MINUTE can not be made editable
>   properly**
>
> When a DateField with Resolution.MINUTE is created as read only and
>   it's state is changed at runtime, hour and minute fields can not be
>   edited. They are rendered as read only. If date field is not created
>   as read only, but it's state is changed at runtime, everything is ok.
>   This bug doesn't exist before version 7.2.1. I'm not sure but it might
>   be related with issue #10262.